# rate limit in twitter api

Tags: api, twitter, rate-limiting

I'm using twitter developer API for my project. I have created an account with my phone number and email address. As you know there are some rate limits in twitter API!

For using API I should create app and user tokens of that app.

My question is that if I create multiple apps for that single account and use them in my project, my rate limit is multiplied by number of apps or requests are aggregated so my rate limit doesn't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is limited by account.

> Rate limiting of the standard API is primarily on a per-user basis —
>   or more accurately described, per user access token. If a method
>   allows for 15 requests per rate limit window, then it allows 15
>   requests per window per access token.

See: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html

Comment: what does this mean? "per user access token"

Comment: I have not used this API before, but I suppose that there is exactly one access token per user account. This token can be generated in the twitter interface: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/access-tokens.html